# How to write Visual Studio unit tests for private C++model layer in MVVM Windows Store app?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mvvm, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I am in the process of writing a fairly complex Windows Store app. To keep the code maintainable, I would like to make good use of unit tests. So far my solutions consists of the following:

1. A C#/XAML project for the app itself and the view layer
2. A C++ Windows Store project wherein the ViewModel layer consists of managed WinRT ref classes while the model layer is straight C++ and entirely hidden from the view layer.
3. A C# Windows Store unit test project to test the ViewModel layer.
4. A C++ project to do some DirectX rendering (part of the view layer and not really relevant for this post)

Testing the C++ WinRT ViewModel classes with the C# project is working fine. It doesn't matter that a different language because everything is public and using the WinRT interface.

However, for testing the model layer classes I am not sure what to do. I would like my test cases to be in a separate project, but I am not sure if this even possible. I want to keep everything here standard C++ for portability reasons. Furthermore, I am trying to keep everything hidden so that I can adhere to strict MVVM design.

How should I write Visual Studio unit tests (like those which are in my ViewModel "Unit Test Library (Windows Store apps)") for my standard C++ model layer?

---

One option I'm looking at right now is to create a "Native Unit Test Project" and use the folder for my model layer project as an include directory for that. Seems like I'm almost there, but I'm getting "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol". How can I build the CPP files for the objects that include with the test project.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a native C++ test project to test your business code. But there are several project settings need to be changed:

1. Set *include path* to your business code, esp. header files.
2. **Include all source code files** in the test project. Or else you will get linker complains `unresolved symbol error`, because *only* header files are included, but *not implementations* (*.cpp).
3. Link/ignore all libs your business code needs. (same as your production project) Don't forget to set correct link path.

Doing this will increase the compile time (same code compiled twice) as well as binary size (all business code has to be compiled/linked in test binaries).

But as far as I know, if your project is not a dynamic/static library, but an executable or some other format cannot export symbols, this is the only way.